# how to connect to a web service in a real Android device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

May I ask if how can I connect to my web service when the ionic application is runned on a real Android device using 'ionic build android'?

I've searched many tutorials about handling CORS in Ionic. I got this tutorial in the Internet (http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) and followed the steps indicated there. I'm using `ionic run android -l -c` and Yes! I can now connect to my web service. The problem is that I am going to deploy my application using `ionic build android` and install it on one or many Android devices. This is to test the simultaneous syncing of data from a network. Unfortunately, the application doesn't display any data from the web service.

BTW, I'm using the IP address of my computer to access my web service in the phone (ex. 121.68.90.134) and the web service is runned under XAMPP v3.2.2 with PHP version 5.6.23 (my computer serves as the temp. server).

Sample URL of the web service: C:/xampp/htdocs/simmlase-WServ/

Here is my app.js code snippets

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

app.constant('Api', {
  url: 'http://192.168.8.100:8100/api'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help. I am confused about this matter because it is needed in my final defense.

Comment: fix ur server to allow cors

Comment: how can I allow cors on my server?